# What did Tao prove in the paper "Almost All Orbits of the Collatz Map Attain Almost Bounded Values''?

Tags: terminology, definition, collatz-conjecture

Last year, Terence Tao published a paper entitled ["Almost All Orbits of the Collatz Map Attain Almost Bounded Values" (via arXiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03562).

In layperson's terms, could somebody please explain what this means?

In particular,

1. "Almost All" — Does that mean with the possible exception of finitely many?
2. "Orbit" — Does that include or exclude *cycles*?
3. "Almost Bounded Values" — What is meant by the term *almost bounded*?

Simply stated, does this mean that the Collatz conjecture is true for "almost all" positive integers?

I am not trying to understand Tao's proof, merely what he proved.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen his own explanation [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/09/10/almost-all-collatz-orbits-attain-almost-bounded-values/)? It's certianly not meant for _complete_ laypeople, but it's meant to provide more intuition than the paper is able to.

Comment: "Almost all" probably means all but a set of density zero. As in, almost all integers are composite. "Orbit" should include cycles, but since (most likely) hardly any orbits are cycles, it wouldn't make any difference to the result.

Comment: For future reference, you can use " (a.k.a. "smart quotes") instead of `` and '' (single apostrophe, repeated) and this will appear as intended, in contrast with what happens in LaTeX.

Comment: Some infinities are larger than others. I think the term "almost all" here is quite misleading to the layperson, actually there could be infinitely many counter examples, but the counter examples are out numbered infinitely many times by the numbers that work, so the probability of finding one of those infinite counter examples in an infinitely larger sea of numbers is zero. Infinity is a weird thing! It's a bit like saying almost all numbers are NOT prime. But yet, there are infinitely many primes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all

Answer (score 7):

**Q1:** No, it's slightly weaker than that. As described in the [blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/09/10/almost-all-collatz-orbits-attain-almost-bounded-values/), "almost all" means in the sense of [logarithmic density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density), which is a somewhat technical concept that roughly means that the set of counterexamples has "probability zero." Formally it means the set of counterexamples is a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{a \in A, a \le n} \frac{1}{a}}{\log n} = 0.$$

Any finite set has logarithmic density $0$ but some infinite sets also do, such as the squares and the primes.

**Q2:** The orbit of an integer $N$ under the Collatz map $\text{Col}$ is the entire sequence $\{ N, \text{Col}(N), \text{Col}^2(N), \dots \}$, so yes, it includes cycles if $N$ ends up in a cycle.

**Q3:** As described in the [blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/09/10/almost-all-collatz-orbits-attain-almost-bounded-values/), "almost bounded" is unfortunately a somewhat technical concept again. It means that if $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is any function such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \infty$ then the smallest number $\text{Col}_{\text{min}}(N)$ in the Collatz orbit of $N$ satisfies $\text{Col}_{\text{min}}(N) \le f(N)$ for "almost all" $N$ (where "almost all" means in the sense of logarithmic density). If we could take $f(n) = 1$ (or any other small constant) and this were true for all $N$ then this would be equivalent to the Collatz conjecture; what Tao shows is that we can take $f$ to grow *arbitrarily slowly* to infinity, so for example we can take $f(N) = \log \log \log \log N$ (for $N$ large enough that this is defined). We can even take a function growing as slowly as the [inverse Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse), a function that famously grows so slowly that for all practical purposes it is at most $5$.

**Q4:**

> Simply stated, does this mean that the Collatz conjecture is true for "almost all" positive integers?

No. The second "almost" is important; Tao shows it's "almost" true for "almost all" positive integers, where both "almost"s have distinct and technical meanings.